# Attribute Error: 'List' object has no attribute 'shape' . Error while trying to train the model with multiple features( multiple arrays)

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, training-data, model-fitting

I have two arrays **"train_vol"** and **"train_time"** with **shape (164,6790)** and one array **"train_cap"** with **shape(164,1)**. I want to train the model like this... **inputs--> train_vol and train_time  output--> train_cap** .....**validation inputs --> val_vol,val_time and validation output --> val_cap**....shape of val_vol,val_time is (42,6790) and val_cap is (42,1) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f3Rb.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f3Rb.png)

I am trying to use model.fit() to train the model.I tried giving **2 arrays as input** to variable x** and **1 array to output variable y**. But I am getting an error as shown.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj0MX.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj0MX.png)

The document says I can give list of arrays as input. So i have tried but i am getting the following error as shown in the picture. Can Anyone let me know where I have done a mistake?[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCQil.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCQil.png)

Comment: If your model contains 2 Input layers only then you can use a List of arrays as input.

Comment: Thank you @AniketBote For further clarification...Both my inputs are n-dimensional arrays(each input array has 164 rows). So if I want to assign each row of the n-dimensional array to an individual neuron in the input layer(I want to use 164 neurons in each input layer). Is this possible? If yes, please let me know using a sample code how to implement it. Thank you :)

Comment: One way that I can think of is to create 164 Input layers with input shape (1,). Then split your dataset into individual rows. ie You will have 164 NumPy arrays or lists. Then feed each array/list to the 164 input layers that you created in the model by passing the dictionary mapping of those arrays to input layer to your model.fit() as shown in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a model which takes multiple inputs as well as multiple output using functional API.

```
def create_model3():
    input1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(13,), name = 'I1')
    input2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(6,), name = 'I2')
    
    hidden1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 4, activation='relu')(input1)
    hidden2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 4, activation='relu')(input2)
    merge = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([hidden1, hidden2])
    hidden3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 3, activation='relu')(merge)
    output1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2, activation='softmax', name ='O1')(hidden3)
    output2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2, activation='softmax', name = 'O2')(hidden3)
    
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = [input1,input2], outputs = [output1,output2])
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

You can specify the connection between your layers using the syntax above. Your model can have more than 2 inputs. The model constructed using above code looks like this.

Note that `13` and `6` in the Input layers represent features in your respective data.

[image: Model Visualization]

For training the model you can use the following syntax:

```
history = model.fit(
    x = {'I1':train_data, 'I2':new_train_data}, 
    y = {'O1':train_labels, 'O2': new_train_labels},
    batch_size = 32,
    epochs = 10,
    verbose = 1,
    callbacks = None,
    validation_data = [(val_data,new_val_data),(val_labels, new_val_labels)]
)
```

Here train_data and new_train_data are two separate data entities.
Note: You can also pass List instead of dictionary but the dictionary is more readable in terms of coding.

For more information on Functional API. You can check this link: [Functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional)

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable response. I think this will definitely help me to create the desired model. :)

Comment: Yea..Just accepted the answer and upvoted it. But maybe it will not be showing up because I'm very new here with less than 15 reputations.... I have a few more doubts. It would be great if you can share with me your email id or Whatsapp number so that we can communicate easily. ( Only if you don't mind) :) Thank you @Aniket Bote

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the arguments as

```
model.fit(x=(train_vol, train_time), ..)
```

Use `()` instead of `[]`. The reason behind is that model can't decide if you are trying to give a dataset of 2 samples or two concurrent datasets. The first case means two datasets, the latter means a dataset with two samples.